# xpath to extract root name node and then turn into a where's clause in Hive sql

Tags: xml, xpath, hive

I have created a view in Hive with xpath statements to extract out data from large message string containing xml data from another table in hive which is loaded with data from log files produced by an internal system.
The log files contain various transactions starting with a particular name node and my hive view only extracts the data for a particular transaction, the issue is that the query results returns the data that matches the xpath statements but also returns the rows that don't match as an empty array.
I only want to return the rows that match the results and ignore the rest with a 'where' statement in the view to look for the transaction type only.

I am no xpath 1.0 guru and I am struggling to find the correct xpath to find the root node name, in this case **'GetTrolleyDetails'** and then turn that into a where's statement to either ignore all that don't match  or only when the transactions name matches the node name

I have suppplied an example of a transaction I am dealing with below;

```
<GetTrolleyDetails xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <accountSession xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <SessionId>59e1f5e1-ef7c-42bc-a236-4086a2aa6a72</b:SessionId>
     <SessionToken i:nil="true">
    </SessionToken>
   </accountSession>
</GetTrolleyDetails>
```

sample of an xpath in view;

```
xpath_string(regexp_replace(message, 'xmlns="', 'xmlns:ns="'), '//accountSession/SessionId[text()]') as SessionId
```

Comment: The condition that you would like to use is a little unclear to me. Are you trying to filter for a specific session id? Should the session id be in the result set (as is currently coded in the XPath expression) or shall it be the `<accountSession>`?

Comment: Hi, hopefully this will clear it up further. The table where the data exists contains 30 different transaction in the 'Message' column but I want to filter the results and only return the data that matches the xpath in the view e.g.  1.`<GetTrolleyDetails xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></GetTrolleyDetails>`  
 2. `<PurchaseInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></PurchaseInfo>` 3.
`<ProfileDetails xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></ProfileDetails>`, there are three transactions, I only want to return the ones starting with `<GetTrolleyDetails `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time playing around with various xpath expressions and finally found the solution to my own issue.

The follow xpath `local-name(/*)')` returns me the root node name of `GetTrolleyDetails` and when I use it in my where clause with the following statement

```
where xpath_string(regexp_replace(message, 'xmlns="', 'xmlns:ns="'), 'local-name(/*)')='GetTrolleyDetails';
```

only the results that match the xpaths in my view are returned in my result. I no longer get empty arrays returned in the result set which was the goal

Answer (score 0):

Didn't fully understand the question but if you want to use a where clause I'd go with the existsNode:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(XMLDATA),XPATH EXPRESSION)
FROM TABLE/VIEW
WHERE existsNode((XMLDATA), XPATH EXPRESSION) =1;
```

If I fully understand the condition I would give an example but sounds like you want to just get a particular transaction which would be involved in the where part.

Oracle Docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions048.htm